# Find real number $x$ such that both $x+\sqrt{2022}$ and $\frac{3}{x}-\sqrt{2022}$ is an integer

Tags: real-numbers, integers

I have some difficulty to do this problem:

Find real number $x$ such that both $x+\sqrt{2022}$ and $\frac{3}{x}-\sqrt{2022}$ is an integer

My attempts: I tried to addition and multiple $x+\sqrt{2022}$ and $\frac{3}{x}-\sqrt{2022}$  together but it seems doesn't help

Anyone have idea on how to solve this? Thank you so much

Comment: $x = n - \sqrt{2022}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Maybe putting this in $3/x - \sqrt{2022}$ will help?

Comment: @L.F. ohhh, thank you so much for your idea!!! I solved it with your idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $2022$ doesn't contain a square (as $2022=2*3*337$). So the solution must be of the form $x=n-\sqrt{2022}$ to satisfy the first equation, where $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Injection in the 2nd equation:
$$\frac3{n-\sqrt{2022}}-\sqrt{2022}\in\mathbb Z$$
We multiply numerator/denominator by $n+\sqrt{2022}$:
$$\frac{3(n+\sqrt{2022})}{n^2-2022}-\sqrt{2022}\in\mathbb Z$$
The denominator must be 3 so that the two square roots cancel, so $n^2-2022=3$ and then $n=45$ or $n=-45$.

Comment: I think that $n^2-2022=3$ then n=45 or -45

Comment: @Lini this is correct, I modified.